# doubleclick an element in beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I can't get the text by using xpath in beautifulsoup but selenium can get that text by using doubleclick command. How can I get the element by using beautifulsoup?

I tried:

```
import requests
from lxml import etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#Function to Find the element from the Xpath
def Xpath(url):
  Dict_Headers = ({'User-Agent':
      'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 \
      (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36',\
      'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})
  # Gets the requried data https browser's address bar
  webPage = requests.get(url,Dict_Headers)
  # Creating a soup Object from the html content
  Scraping = BeautifulSoup(webPage.content, "html.parser") 
  # Conveting Soup object to etree object for Xpath processing
  documentObjectModel = etree.HTML(str(Scraping)) 
  return (documentObjectModel.xpath("//div[@id='pages']/div/section/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]")[0].text)
URL = "http://..."
print(Xpath(URL))
```

doubleclick command in selenium is that:

```
selenium.doubleClick("xpath=//div[@id='pages']/div/section/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]")
```

The thing that I want to get is "0" from screenshot inspected:

[image: The thing that I want to get is "0"]

Comment: What's the URL?

Comment: mgm.gov.tr/tahmin/il-ve-ilceler.aspx?il=ANKARA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need neither selenium nor beautifulSoup for that. There's an API that the data is fetched from.

Here's how to get that part your XPath points to:

```py
import requests

url = "https://servis.mgm.gov.tr/web/sondurumlar?merkezid=90601"
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0",
    "Referer": "https://mgm.gov.tr/",
    "Origin": "https://mgm.gov.tr",
}

data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()[0]

for k, v in data.items():
    print(f"{k}: {v}")
```

Output:

```
aktuelBasinc: 911.6
denizSicaklik: -9999
denizeIndirgenmisBasinc: 1009
gorus: 20000
hadiseKodu: AB
istNo: 17130
kapalilik: 2
karYukseklik: -9999
nem: 25
rasatMetar: -9999
rasatSinoptik: -9999
rasatTaf: -9999
ruzgarHiz: 13.32
ruzgarYon: 36
sicaklik: 29.7
veriZamani: 2022-06-01T09:10:00.000Z
yagis00Now: 0
yagis10Dk: 0
yagis12Saat: 0
yagis1Saat: 0
yagis24Saat: 0
yagis6Saat: 0
denizVeriZamani: 2022-06-01T09:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: Perfect api, thank you. Nevertheless, I think "doubleclick" activity should be involved in the beautiful soup package.

Comment: @fyec BeautifulSoup is a tool made to parse html. It is not made to interact with the browser. It's like saying, "I think this hammer should be able to solder these electrical components.", or  "I think this printer should be able to change the brightness on my monitor."

Comment: @chitown88 well said!

Comment: Hahaha :)), excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Sorry, How where did you get url from (?merkezid=90601)?

Comment: From the Developer's Tool -> Network tab.